# Calling setInterval from a self-executing function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, firefox4

The following way to call **setInterval** seems to work in Firefox 3.5 and Chromium 10.0 but not in Firefox 4.

```
var setInterval;
(function runmenow () {
  setInterval(function () { document.write('hello<br />'); }, 1000);
}());
```

Firebug tells me that *"setInterval is not a function"*. Why isn't setInterval available in this context?

Comment: You can not use document.write after the initial page load or maybe you want to write over the entire page.

Comment: @epascarello, that is not the issue in the q, but true, that could be an issue

Comment: @epascarello I'm only using document.write as a toy example and the problem doesn't seem to be related to it. But yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 7):

This (i believe) is because you are setting setInterval as null in that first line.

just do:

```
//var setInterval; <--remove
(function runmenow () {
  setInterval(function () { document.write('hello<br />'); }, 1000);
}());
```

Comment: `var setInterval` sets `setInterval` to `undefined`, not `null`

Comment: Sorry, but removing the var definition doesn't seem to help. Without the definition, setInterval still works in e.g. Chrome but not in Firefox 4. However, without the var definition, Firebug doesn't give the error.

Comment: @Matti, no idea what to tell u